# Is it possible to unwrap and map selected faces, then unwrap and map other selected faces?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is it possible to select some faces then unwrap them and map them with image, then select some other faces then unwrap and map them, and so on? I have one quite complex model, which if I unwrap them at once, it seems some faces are missing from the unwrapped model, which I don't know why.

Comment: Yes it's is possible and that's how mostly how we are work with complex models. We would place seams at the location we need and unwrap portion of the model one by one. Sometimes we have different UV maps in different channel for different purposes. Eg. One uv for baking Ambient occlusion and a second one for applying texture to the model.

Comment: Tried it, maybe I am doing it wrong, my previous mapping are affected by current mapping.

Comment: The best way to learn how is to go on youtube as search for tutorials on the subject and learn from blenderguru or blender cookie guys. Writing how to proper step by step UV unwrap for a complex model , is probably too much for a site like stackexchange. Unless you have a simplified model part which we can discuss on. Without images and file to work with, it's hard to tell what is the difficulty you are faced with.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I have done it wrong. I tried it again and it worked well. I am using a simplified model, it is the default box, which I tried to map it three faces at a time. First trial didn't work because, silly me, I didn't put any seams on the faces. Second trial, I tried to do it step by step and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

This should be done with face assignment too beside uv mapping. So select some faces, assign the material to the faces. then put seams and unwrap, then map with image. After this is done, select some other faces, assign new material to the faces, put seams and unwrap, and map with other image, and so on. Can't be done with just one material.